Transfer .php script to decode and uncompress binary files into Power Query
I have a MySQL Database where .xlsx Files are stored as binaries. I can download these binaries and transform them back into .xlsx files with the following .php script (all at once in a folder).
<?php

$scan = glob(__DIR__ . '/*.bin');

foreach ($scan as $filePath) {
    if (is_file($filePath)) {
      $content = gzuncompress(base64_decode(file_get_contents($filePath)));

      file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/' . basename($filePath, '.bin') . '.xlsx', $content);
    }
}

Now I want to do the same transformation in Power Query for Power BI, so that I can look directly into the binary files without having to download and transform them before.
After many searches I think, this line of code should work. I take the Binary, Decompress it via GZip and transform it into an Excel file.
= Table.AddColumn(billing_T_ARCHIVE_SUBSIDIARY, "ExcelFile", each Excel.Workbook(Binary.Decompress([FILE], Compression.GZip)))
In Power Query it looks like this:

The error message is:
"DataFormat.Error: The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream."
If I change the binary to text within Power Query and it looks the same

So I changed the code to this, but same error:
 Table.AddColumn(#"Transformed Column", "ExcelFile", each Excel.Workbook(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText([FILE], BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.GZip)))
I can split up the .php script into one decoding part:
foreach ($scan as $filePath) {
if (is_file($filePath)) {
  $content = base64_decode(file_get_contents($filePath));

  file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/' . basename($filePath, '.bin') . '_1.bin', $content);
}

}
And one uncompressing part.
foreach ($scan as $filePath) {
if (is_file($filePath)) {
  $content = gzuncompress(file_get_contents($filePath));

  file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/' . basename($filePath, '_1.bin') . '.xlsx', $content);
}

}
The file in between looks weird when I open it with the editor:

PowerBI shows the same, when I import this decoded file:

I am not really sure, where the problem is, I can only find solutions for uncompressed zip files in Power Query, but this don't really help since in my opinion, the compression and encoding must somehow be the problem.

It sounds like the problem is with the Base64 decoding. Power Query is telling you that it does not recognise your binary data as a gzip file, therefore either the binary data is still Base64 encoded or Power Query cannot decompress the gzip file for some reason. If possible, can you manually import a decoded gzip file into Power Query and see how the binary data is previewed?

Just to confirm, how is the binary data imported into Power Query? Is it possible that another process is modifying the gzip files in some way?

Thank you Noel for your ideas. I could import the decoded files into Power Query, but when I want to decompress it, it gives me an error:
Expression.Error: Invalid binary encoding.
Details:
x�\�S�.M�5
(which are the first lines of the decoded binary, but apparently they are not recognised correctly)

Can you decode the file in your PHP script but let Power Query do the gzip decompression? There is also the possibility that the gzip implementation in PHP is not 100% compatible with the implementation in Power Query. Just to confirm, after you Base64-decode your binary data from the database you should have a valid gzip file (saved with .gz extension) and then after you decompress the gzip file you will have the .xlsx file.

In your code have you tried Binary.Decompress(File.Contents([FILE]),Compression.GZip) instead of Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText([FILE]), Compression.GZip)?
